# Gitkraken: Hide all branches within a folder

Tags: git, gitkraken

Gitkraken allows for the hiding/soloing of branches through the *Branch actions* menu.  The hide feature will hide all commits made on that branch.  In my case, this would hide all commits on develop but would not hide all of the feature branches based on develop.

[image: Gitkraken Branch Actions]

The feature folder in the image above does not have a menu for soloing or hiding the contents within, as develop does.  If I want to hide all feature branches, I have to manually hide each one.  Is there a way to do this in bulk?

I do not want to solo develop, I just want to hide all feature branches while viewing develop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, I think it's not possible to hide multiple branches at once.

A wokaround would be to solo `develop` and any other branches you're interested in. So basically you just have to ponder if it's less work to hide one group of branches or to solo the other.

Features like this can be requested via the [GK Slack Channel](https://slack.gitkraken.com) or by [contanct form](https://www.gitkraken.com/contact).